# How to change App Description in Test Flight invitation e-mail?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, testflight

I have an iOS app build ready to test. Some testers have been already testing. However, I need to change this part of Test Flight invitation e-mail for other testers who haven't been invited yet:

[image]

How can I do it? I have already tried:

- Editing TestFlight -> Test Information -> Beta App Description
- Editing TestFlight -> Builds -> my build -> Test Details -> What to Test

with no results. The text in e-mail always remains the same.

Comment: For us `Editing TestFlight -> Test Information -> Beta App Description` works. Could it be, that you have added multiple languages for `Beta App Description`, but added the description only to one?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem: The contents of the email remained the same despite changing the "Beta App Description", etc. It wasn't until I **uploaded a new build** that the new description finally started appearing in the emails.